# How to give padding to text in div?

Tags: css, html

Whenever i give padding to text in div the whole height of div changes, and I have to manage the height according to div.
I have tried with this

its my html

```
<div>Home</div>
```

its the css i use

```
div {
  font-size: 27px; 
  text-align: center; 
  margin: 5px 3px 0 0; 
  margin: 75px 0 0 0;
  float: right; 
  width: 208px; 
  height:100px; 
  border-radius:2px; 
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive;
  background-color: #F00;
  color:#FFF; 
}
```

Here, the text is on top while I want the text to be in centred. Can anybody help?

Comment: the html is "<div>Home</div>"

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pzfm5/

Comment: Why you are giving `float: right` then?

Comment: oh thats according to my design.

Comment: i want a div with a height 100px and text in centre? plz help

Answer (score 2):

Use `line-height: 100px;` for  center text

[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/pzfm5/4/)